# Can't open sql connection in cs file - asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, localhost

I am new to ASP.NET and following a tutorial where a user can register to a site and it checks a database to see if username already exist. When came time to create database, the tutorial said to create it in visual studio (mdf file), but i use MYSQL Workbench, so i created it there and tried connecting it on my own.

When adding the connection under Data Connections in Visual, I was able to see my databases and the test connection worked.

When adding the SQLDataSource, I was able to run a test query successfully and read from the database. I even used it with a GridView to display the data on a web page.

But when it comes to opening a connection in the cs file, i am getting an error.

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5347119
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5358907
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +892
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +646
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +732
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +196
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   Registration.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\WebSite\Registration.aspx.cs:15
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Error appears in code here

```
15 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterCS"].ConnectionString);
16 conn.Open();//ERROR HERE
```

And here is my web.config, just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RegisterCS" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password=******;database=asptest"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>


</configuration>
```

I looked around and apparently it can be the connection string, but i think it should be ok since the data source actually read successfully from the database right? Am I missing something to connect the database properly? Maybe i have to something in Workbench? I also tried with the firewall down. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Connection Strings are `Uid` and `Pwd` in place of `User Id` and `Password` respectively.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html

> The following is a sample connection string:
>
> ```
> Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=12345;Database=test;
> ```
>
> In this example, the `MySqlConnection` object is configured to connect to a MySQL server at `127.0.0.1`, with a user name of `root` and a password of `12345`. The default database for all statements will be the `test` database.

Also, comments discussion led to revealing that the `Port` is not the standard/default of `3306`, but was `5354`. Thus the connection string should be as follows:

```
Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=******;Database=asptest;Port=5354
```

Also, you may **not** need to change `User Id` to `Uid`, and `Password` to `Pwd`, the documentation for the options allows for the following:

> Password, pwd; The password for the MySQL account being used.
>
> User Id, UserID, Username, Uid, User name, User: The MySQL login account being used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Lastly, you'll need the MySQL Connector. Then you'll need to switch your `SqlConnections` out for `MySqlConnections.`

Comment: Thanks for response, but didn't seem to help, getting same error still.

Comment: Is your server online? Are you using the right IP? Is it on the standard port?

Comment: Yes, it should be online, the page with the GridVIew is displaying the right data from database. For the ip, i tried localhost and 127.0.0.1. And for the port, not too familiar with that, how can i check?

Comment: It's on `localhost`? Not on another device? You can use `netstat -tnb` and check for a process that says something along the lines of `mysql`, or check if port `3306` is listed. (That's the default.)

Comment: Ok, ran the netstat and found mysqld.exe running on 127.0.0.1:5354. Also i noticed in my notification tray an icon for asp.net development server, and its running on port 55181

Comment: Since MySQL is on `5354`, you should specify `127.0.0.1:5354` in the `ConnectionString`. Or, it might take `Port=5354` instead. I'm not sure the exact syntax.

Comment: Ok, well correct syntax seems to be "port=...", but i get an error when specifying 5354. i changed it in the web.config, but when i go to update datasource i get an error saying database schema cannot be retrieved for connection. Specifying 3306, lets it pass though.

Comment: Damn,no. Now it says "Keyword not supported: 'port'". But i looked here
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ , and it says it should work.

Comment: I just saw your problem. You're using `SqlConnection` instead of `MySqlConnection`.

Comment: Ok, would you by chance no the namespace to use it?

Comment: You need the MySql Connector. It's on their website.

Comment: Well trying to install MySql Connector basically broke VS haha. Won't be able to verify your solution anytime soon, but if I still can't fix it within a couple days, I will just give you the answer, it sounds about right.